# How to load a file including encoded 2 byte characters

Tags: python, character-encoding

When I write a list of strings of 2 byte characters to a file, encoded strings are stored into the file.

```
x = ["漢字"]
with open("/path/to/char.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(x))
```

/path/to/char.txt

```
['\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe5\xad\x97']
```

I'd like to load and decode the original characters from this file. Unfortunately, with very basic way, it seems impossible:

```
with open("/path/to/char.txt", "r") as f:
    x = f.read()

print x
print list(x)
```

it prints:

```
['\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe5\xad\x97']
['[', "'", '\\', 'x', 'e', '6', '\\', 'x', 'b', 'c', '\\', 'x', 'a', '2', '\\', 'x', 'e', '5', '\\', 'x', 'a', 'd', '\\', 'x', '9', '7', "'", ']']
```

How do I get 2 byte chars `"漢字"` from `char.txt`?

Comment: Any chance of writing them properly to the file in the first place? Or do you need to decode the literal contents of the file as you have them right now?

Comment: @MarkRansom I do not have  a chance of writing strings properly. I need to decode the contents in my file. Thank you.

Comment: you should write `f.write(x[0])` to create correct file without `[ ]` and `' '`

Comment: or use JSON, CSV, YAML to write lists, dictionaries, etc

Comment: @furas please see my previous comment. I need decode the contents in my file.

Comment: remove `[]` and `''` and you get normal text to `decode()` - `x[2:-2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have string `['\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe5\xad\x97']` with `[]` and `''` so remove `[]` and `''` and you get string which you can decode

```
print x[2:-2].decode('string_escape')
```

or again as list

```
lst = [ x[2:-2].decode('string_escape') ]
print lst
```

[7.8.4. Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)

---

**BTW:** you can also use `eval()`

```
x = eval( x )

print x[0]
```

or better `ast`

```
import ast

x = ast.literal_eval(x)

print x[0]
```

---

**EDIT:** more information

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# 7.8.4. Python Specific Encodings
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings

import ast

x = ["漢字"]

print '--- oryginal ---'

print type(x) # <type 'list'>
print repr(x) # ['\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe5\xad\x97']
print x       # ['\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe5\xad\x97']
print x[0]    # 漢字

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(x))

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    x = f.read()

print '--- from file ---'

print type(x) # <type 'str'>                          # <-- str
print repr(x) # "['\\xe6\\xbc\\xa2\\xe5\\xad\\x97']"  # <-- '\\'
print x       # ['\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe5\xad\x97']
print x[0]    # [

print '--- decode ---'

a = x.decode('string_escape')
print type(a) # <type 'str'>                      # <-- str
print repr(a) # "['\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe5\xad\x97']"    # <-- '\'
print a       # ['漢字']
print a[0]    # [

print '--- eval ---'

y = eval(x)
print type(y) # <type 'list'>
print repr(y) # ['\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe5\xad\x97']
print y       # ['\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe5\xad\x97']
print y[0]    # 漢字

print '--- ast ---'

z = ast.literal_eval(x)
print type(z) # <type 'list'>
print repr(z) # ['\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe5\xad\x97']
print z       # ['\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe5\xad\x97']
print z[0]    # 漢字
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `str(x)` produces the python text representation of a list, not the contents of the list. The representation is designed for humans who know python to look at, not for serialization and storage of data.

If you want to write that list as lines of text, you need to decide on an encoding and write the strings line by line. In python 2, use the `codecs`. In python 3, the regular `open` function works.

```
import codecs
x = ["漢字"]
with codecs.open("/path/to/char.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for item in x:
        f.write(item + '\n')
```

Now you have a file with utf-8 encoded lines of text.